# Earning through you YouTube

Tags: youtube

Will I earn anything if I add subtitles to the already uploaded video on YouTube?

Answer (score 1):

People make money on YouTube by uploading videos and then monetizing videos.
The revenue, you end up making from a video, depends on people's engagement with the ads placed on your video. 
As far as I think, subtitles don't effect the engagement on videos. So, I don't think a YouTuber would be willing to share their revenue if you just add subtitles to their videos. 
A more comprehensive answer is given here: https://www.quora.com/How-can-one-earn-money-by-subtitling-YouTube-videos

Answer (score 0):

While you won't earn any money doing it, you can earn points in the [YouTube Contributors program](https://contributors.youtube.com). These points themselves are have no monetary value, but they may get you invited to events, get you some merch and such.